# Multiple COUNTIFS inside IFS formula (FORMULA PARSE ERROR)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Getting "Formula Parse Error" after inputting this. Not sure if I'm missing a comma or parenthesis. I think I I'm following the rules for the [IFS()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7014145?hl=en), the [AND()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093301?hl=en&ref_topic=3105413) and the [COUNTIFS()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256550?hl=en). Also not sure if there is a simpler way of writing this formula or if its best to use Google Apps Script.

I notice that this formula only works if I have 1 pair of arguments for IFS() (so that would be the first AND() and the first COUNTIFS(), but when I try to add another pair of arguments, then I get the formula parse error.

I had no problems putting COUNTIFS() inside an IF(), but due to the limitations with IF(), I had to give IFS() a try so that I can address more specific combinations of conditions.

```
IFS
(
AND($S$1 = "Include Both", $V$1 = "Any", $S$2 = "All"), 

    COUNTIFS
    ( 
        INDIRECT("'Activity Log'!$A$3:$A"), $N6, 
        INDIRECT("'Activity Log'!$E$3:$E"), "="&U$3,
        INDIRECT("'Activity Log'!$I$3:$I"), ">="&$N$1,
        INDIRECT("'Activity Log'!$I$3:$I"), "<="&$N$2
    ),

AND($S$1 = "Include Both", $V$1 != "Any", $S$2 = "All"),

    COUNTIFS
    (
        INDIRECT("'Activity Log'!$O$3:$O"), "="&$V$1, 
        INDIRECT("'Activity Log'!$A$3:$A"), $N6, 
        INDIRECT("'Activity Log'!$E$3:$E"), "="&U$3,
        INDIRECT("'Activity Log'!$I$3:$I"), ">="&$N$1 ,
        INDIRECT("'Activity Log'!$I$3:$I"), "<="&$N$2
    ),

AND($S$1 = "Include Both", $V$1 = "Any", $S$2 != "All"),

    COUNTIFS
    (
        INDIRECT("'Activity Log'!$A$3:$A"), $N6, 
        INDIRECT("'Activity Log'!$E$3:$E"), "="&U$3,
        INDIRECT("'Activity Log'!$I$3:$I"), ">="&$N$1 ,
        INDIRECT("'Activity Log'!$I$3:$I"), "<="&$N$2,  
        INDIRECT("'Activity Log'!$H$3:$H"), "="&$S$2
    ),

AND($S$1 = "Include Both", $V$1 != "Any", $S$2 != "All"),

    COUNTIFS
    (
    
        INDIRECT("'Activity Log'!$O$3:$O"), "="&$V$1, 
        INDIRECT("'Activity Log'!$A$3:$A"), $N6, 
        INDIRECT("'Activity Log'!$E$3:$E"), "="&U$3,
        INDIRECT("'Activity Log'!$I$3:$I"), ">="&$N$1,
        INDIRECT("'Activity Log'!$I$3:$I"), "<="&$N$2,  
        INDIRECT("'Activity Log'!$H$3:$H"), "="&$S$2
        
    ),

AND($S$1 != "Include Both", $V$1 = "Any", $S$2 = "All"),

    COUNTIFS
    (
    
        INDIRECT("'Activity Log'!$A$3:$A"), $N6, 
        INDIRECT("'Activity Log'!$E$3:$E"), "="&U$3,
        INDIRECT("'Activity Log'!$I$3:$I"), ">="&$N$1,
        INDIRECT("'Activity Log'!$I$3:$I"), "<="&$N$2, 
        INDIRECT("'Activity Log'!$M$3:$M"), "="&$S$1 
    ),

AND($S$1 != "Include Both", $V$1 != "Any", $S$2 = "All"),

    COUNTIFS
    (
    
        INDIRECT("'Activity Log'!$O$3:$O"), "="&$V$1, 
        INDIRECT("'Activity Log'!$A$3:$A"), $N6, 
        INDIRECT("'Activity Log'!$E$3:$E"), "="&U$3,
        INDIRECT("'Activity Log'!$I$3:$I"), ">="&$N$1,
        INDIRECT("'Activity Log'!$I$3:$I"), "<="&$N$2, 
        INDIRECT("'Activity Log'!$M$3:$M"), "="&$S$1 
        
        
    ),

AND($S$1 != "Include Both", $V$1 != "Any", $S$2 != "All"),

    COUNTIFS
    (
        INDIRECT("'Activity Log'!$O$3:$O"), "="&$V$1, 
        INDIRECT("'Activity Log'!$A$3:$A"), $N6, 
        INDIRECT("'Activity Log'!$E$3:$E"), "="&U$3,
        INDIRECT("'Activity Log'!$I$3:$I"), ">="&$N$1,
        INDIRECT("'Activity Log'!$I$3:$I"), "<="&$N$2, 
        INDIRECT("'Activity Log'!$M$3:$M"), "="&$S$1, 
        INDIRECT("'Activity Log'!$H$3:$H"), "="&$S$2
    ),

AND($S$1 != "Include Both", $V$1 = "Any", $S$2 != "All"),

    COUNTIFS
    (
        INDIRECT("'Activity Log'!$A$3:$A"), $N6, 
        INDIRECT("'Activity Log'!$E$3:$E"), "="&U$3,
        INDIRECT("'Activity Log'!$I$3:$I"), ">="&$N$1,
        INDIRECT("'Activity Log'!$I$3:$I"), "<="&$N$2, 
        INDIRECT("'Activity Log'!$M$3:$M"), "="&$S$1, 
        INDIRECT("'Activity Log'!$H$3:$H"), "="&$S$2
    )
)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `INDIRECT` in your formula?

Comment: @idfurw The other sheet I'm tallying from has rows that auto insert at the top row. So I need to freeze the range to count from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`!=` is not supported comparison operator, you should use `<>`

---

If A and/or E is a number. Please remove the single quotes

i.e.   `"A='",N6,"' and ",` to   `"A=",N6," and ",`

```
=QUERY(INDIRECT("'Activity Log'!A3:O"),CONCATENATE("select count(A) where ",
  "A='",N6,"' and ",
  "E='",U3,"' and ",
  "I>=",N1," and ",
  "I<=",N2,
  IF(V1="Any",," and O='"&V1&"'"),
  IF(S2="All",," and H='"&S2&"'"),
  IF(S1="Include Both",," and M='"&S1&"'"),
" label count(A) ''"),0)
```

Comment: Added a simpler formula, could you please try?

Comment: Fixed. Please try again. You could debug by checking the `CONCATENATE` itself.

Comment: You can also list all the matched records by changing `select count(A)` into `select *` and removing `" label count(A) ''"`

Comment: I now get #N/A when it should have returned 3.

Comment: Please share a copy of your sheet